# Using JSoup to parse a String with Clojure

Tags: java, web-scraping, clojure, jsoup

Using JSoup to parse a html string with Clojure, the source as the following

Dependencies

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
               [org.jsoup/jsoup "1.13.1"]]
```

Source code

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
(def HTML (str "<html><head><title>Website title</title></head>
                <body><p>Sample paragraph number 1 </p>
                      <p>Sample paragraph number 2</p>
                </body></html>"))

(defn fetch_html [html]
  (let [soup (Jsoup/parse html)
        titles (.title soup)
        paragraphs (.getElementsByTag soup "p")]
    {:title titles :paragraph paragraphs}))

(fetch_html HTML)
```

Expected result

```
{:title "Website title", 
 :paragraph ["Sample paragraph number 1" 
             "Sample paragraph number 2"]}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not as expected

```
user ==> (fetch_html HTML)
{:title "Website title", :paragraph []}
```

Comment: Did you try to pass "p" instead of "a" to the getElementsByTag method?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the versions used etc. Your code [WFM](https://gist.github.com/christoph-frick/d1fbd32f910993b981fad54692efe2e5#file-gistfile1-txt). The use of `str` there is not needed (neither is the import) - but that should not harm the result.

Comment: @cfrick :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [org.jsoup/jsoup "1.13.1"]] , thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(.getElementsByTag ...) returns a sequence of Element's, you need to call .text() method on each element to get the text value. I'm using Jsoup ver 1.13.1.

```clj
(ns core
  (:import (org.jsoup Jsoup))
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(def HTML (str "<html><head><title>Website title</title></head>
                <body><p>Sample paragraph number 1 </p>
                      <p>Sample paragraph number 2</p>
                </body></html>"))

(defn fetch_html [html]
  (let [soup (Jsoup/parse html)
        titles (.title soup)
        paragraphs (.getElementsByTag soup "p")]
    {:title titles :paragraph (mapv #(.text %) paragraphs)}))

(fetch_html HTML)
```

Also consider using Reaver, which is a Clojure library that wraps JSoup, or any other wrappers like others have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I have a [Clojure wrapper for TagSoup](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.01.05/api/tupelo.parse.tagsoup) that might be useful. Try running it in this [template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  To use in your project, add the line:

```
[tupelo "21.01.05"]
```

to your `:dependencies` in `project.clj`.

---

The code example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.parse.tagsoup :as tagsoup]
    ))

(dotest
  (let [html "<html>
                <head><title>Website title</title></head>
                <body><p>Sample paragraph number 1 </p>
                      <p>Sample paragraph number 2</p>
                </body></html>"]
    (is= (tagsoup/parse html)
      {:tag     :html,
       :attrs   {},
       :content [{:tag     :head,
                  :attrs   {},
                  :content [{:tag :title, :attrs {}, :content ["Website title"]}]}
                 {:tag     :body,
                  :attrs   {},
                  :content [{:tag :p, :attrs {}, :content ["Sample paragraph number 1 "]}
                            {:tag :p, :attrs {}, :content ["Sample paragraph number 2"]}]}]})))
```

---

**Details**

If you look at the source code, you can readily see why you want to use a wrapper function!

```
(ns tupelo.parse.tagsoup
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.parse.xml :as xml]
    [tupelo.string :as ts]
    [tupelo.schema :as tsk]))

(s/defn ^:private tagsoup-parse-fn
  [input-source :- org.xml.sax.InputSource
   content-handler]
  (doto (org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.)
    (.setFeature "http://www.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/features/default-attributes" false)
    (.setFeature "http://www.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/features/cdata-elements" true)
    (.setFeature "http://www.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/features/ignorable-whitespace" true)
    (.setContentHandler content-handler)
    (.setProperty "http://www.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/properties/auto-detector"
      (proxy [org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.AutoDetector] []
        (autoDetectingReader [^java.io.InputStream is]
          (java.io.InputStreamReader. is "UTF-8"))))
    (.setProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler" content-handler)
    (.parse input-source)))

; #todo make use string input:  (ts/string->stream html-str)
(s/defn parse-raw :- tsk/KeyMap
  "Loads and parse an HTML resource and closes the input-stream."
  [html-str :- s/Str]
  (xml/parse-raw-streaming
    (org.xml.sax.InputSource.
      (ts/string->stream html-str))
    tagsoup-parse-fn))

; #todo make use string input:  (ts/string->stream html-str)
(s/defn parse :- tsk/KeyMap
  "Loads and parse an HTML resource and closes the input-stream."
  [html-str :- s/Str]
  (xml/enlive-remove-whitespace
    (xml/enlive-normalize
      (parse-raw
        html-str))))
```

Comment: I shall try to embed into my code. Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Please see the update.  Don't embed, just use the library via a reference in `project.clj`